# dropdownlist in a footer of gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have asp grid view and i created 4 columns(Id,Name,quantity,price) and a footer. i have bounded all the 4 columns from the database. in the footer template, i added a dropdown list item.
every thing is working fine but, the problem is in the footer templalte dropdownlist  is added after all the 4 columns but i want to add the dropdown footer to the 2nd column(Name).

Please apologise for my english n Help me

I used the following code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_page2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
            CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" ShowFooter="True"> 
          <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
          <FooterStyle BackColor="Black" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
          <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
          <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
          <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
          <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
          <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
          <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField  DataField="PRO_ID" HeaderText="PRO_ID" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="NAME" ItemStyle-Width="100px"/>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
          <ItemTemplate> <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PRICE" ItemStyle-Width="80px"/>
          <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="TOTAL_PRICE"/>
          <asp:TemplateField>
          <FooterTempenter code herelate >
          <asp:DropDownList  ID="ftrDDL" runat="server" DataTextField="PRO_ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="" Width="130px" EnableViewState="true" >
          <asp:ListItem Text="SELECT ONE" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
          </FooterTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to modify the template of second column

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" Text='<%#     Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %>'
                    runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ftrDDL" runat="server" DataTextField="PRO_ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                    DataSourceID="" Width="130px" EnableViewState="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="SELECT ONE" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have not tested the code but this should work .Let me know if it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Is it required you add the drop down list in the footer?

I would suggest adding the drop down to the Name column. The footer will always load last.

Answer (score 0):

Use template filed for Name

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_page2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
            BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black"
            GridLines="Vertical" ShowFooter="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PRO_ID" HeaderText="PRO_ID" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ftrDDL" runat="server" DataTextField="PRO_ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                            DataSourceID="" Width="130px" EnableViewState="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PRICE" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
                    <ItemStyle Width="80px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="TOTAL_PRICE" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```